Sympy CAS functions in libreoffice calc cells
Is there a way to use sympy from libreoffice calc cells?
I want to use sympy's CAS functions. Say I want to integrate formulas in cells.

The question is really just whether you can call python code from libreoffice. If you can then you can call sympy.

On Linux, install sympy in your system python. Should be easy, so probably you asked because you're not using Linux.
On Windows, try get-pip.py and see if you can install the library into the python bundled with LibreOffice. For details, see: How update Libre Office Python on windows?
